# this.response.end("hello") in data or content of receiving end?

Tags: node.js, meteor

I'm following an example from the Iron:Router [docs](http://iron-meteor.github.io/iron-router/). Is there a way to determine if the response will be in the `data` or `content` or both? It seems to only be in the response `content` if I do `this.response.end(something)`, but will be in both the response `data` and `content` if I do `this.response.end(JSON.stringify(something))`

```
Router.route('/access/fullstack/invert-matrices', function () {
  var reply = "hello from the server\n");
  this.response.end(reply);
}, {where: 'server'});
```

Note that code on the receiving end is also written in JavaScript/Meteor:

```
var url = 'https://saturnapi.com/access/fullstack/invert-matrices'
var options = {
  'headers' : {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    'saturnapi-access-key': apiKey,
  },
  'data': {
    'SaturnParams': SaturnParams
  }
};

var result = HTTP.post(url, options);
```

And an example of a response containing my intended response in both `content` and `data`:

```
{
  "statusCode": 200,
  "content": "\"\\\"[1.000000 0.500000]\\\"\"",
  "headers": {
    "vary": "Accept-Encoding",
    "access-control-allow-origin": "*",
    "access-control-allow-headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
  },
  "data": "\"[1.000000 0.500000]\""
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by _`data`_? Do you mean inside the `res`-object?

Comment: I mean the `data` field on the end receiving the response

Comment: Sorry, but 't get it. There is no _`data`_ field in HTTP. Can you tell be how you retrieve this _`data`_ field?

Comment: you are asking about the code on the receiving end, but you are not showing that code. HTTP has no objects. What you are asking about is the interface you are using to retrieve and parse the HTTP response. Please show that code and maybe we can help you then.